error when creating payment method with payment element react js
trying to create a payment and save the card to the user but with the PaymentElement it is not being saved
but I need to save it in this format :#
doc
the backend generates the client_secret and validates the token and generates the payment with the client
const handleSubmit_payment = async(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!stripe /* || !elements */) {
            setdisabledButton(false);
            return;
        }
 
        const {error: submitError} = await elements.submit();
        if (submitError) {
            setdisabledButton(false);
        return;
        }
 
        const {error, confirmationToken} = await stripe.createConfirmationToken({
            elements,
            params: {
              payment_method_data: {
                billing_details: {
                  name: Users.name,
                }
              }
            }
        });
 
        const sum = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}/confirmationTokens`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`
              },
            body: JSON.stringify({ token: confirmationToken.id })
          });
       
          const summary = await sum.json();
          console.log(summary)
 
        const res = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}/pay`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              token: confirmationToken,
              amount: 351.21
            }),
          });
     
          const { client_secret: clientSecret } = await res.json();
 
        if (error) {
            // This point is only reached if there's an immediate error when
            // creating the ConfirmationToken. Show the error to your customer (for example, payment details incomplete)
            handleError(error);
            return;
        }
 
        console.log(confirmationToken)
 
        const {errors} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
            //elements,
            clientSecret,
            confirmParams: {
              confirmation_token: confirmationToken.id,
              return_url: 'https://example.com/order/123/complete',
            },
          });
    }

generates the payment but does not save the card
The only way I found is Card Element but I need to do it with the PaymentElement form

Can you show the code for the backend Payment Intent you're creating? That's where you would set the card to be saved (i.e. with setup_future_usage='off_session')

$stripe = new StripeClient(config('services.stripe.key_secret'));
        $paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
            'amount' => $this->dollarsToCents($request->amount),
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'customer' => $customer->stripe_id,
            'setup_future_usage'=>'off_session',
        ]);


You mentioned it "generates the payment", do you mean by this that the payment is succeeded? If not what status is it in?

yes, generates the payment

not save card :/

So, the payment was accepted and successfully processed, but the payment method was not saved in the user's profile?

exactly,not saved in the user profile
